# Cannot use unique_ptr inside a map in a vector?

Tags: c++11, std, visual-studio-2019

I would like to use `unique_ptr` inside `map` in `vector`. But I got an error message.
I am not sure why and how to solve this problem. 
This is the code.

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::string>>> outputContainers;
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> outputContainer;
    outputContainer[0] = std::make_unique<std::string>("test");
    outputContainers.push_back(std::move(outputContainer));
}
```

This is an error message.

```
Error C2280 'std::pair<const int,std::unique_ptr<std::string,std::default_delete<std::string>>>::pair(const std::pair<const int,std::unique_ptr<std::string,std::default_delete<std::string>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function test C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xmemory  671
```

Comment: [It works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/xWL_s8 "Compiler Explorer link"), as long as I add the other necessary headers.

Comment: @DanielH Could you tell me which order did you install which library and which version of visual studio do you use?

Comment: @DanielH There is difference between G++ and CL.EXE compiler from visual.

Comment: @rafix07 Yeah, I see that when I switch to the latest MSVC compiler there, it fails. It looks like it’s trying to call a copy constructor instead of a move constructor? I think that’s an issue with MSVC and the standard says it should work, not that this actually helps much.

Comment: @rafix07 With VS2015, it works fine for me. Which version you have problems with?

Comment: @Gupta I am using VS2019. If I use G++, it works fine.

Comment: Even just `std::vector<std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::string>>> outputContainers; outputContainers.resize(1);` already fails. Somehow, the vector chooses to copy, and not to move, elements when resizing. I seem to remember that something needs to be `noexcept` to allow the vector to move on reallocation.

Comment: Gcc and clang compiles this but not msvc. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zvd1TEdsY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a vector needs to reallocate, it may move elements to the new storage if [the element's type `is_nothrow_move_constructible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874310/using-an-object-without-copy-and-without-a-noexcept-move-constructor-in-a-vector); otherwise, it has to copy (so it can unwind back to the original state if any constructor throws an exception).

`std::map`'s move constructor [is not required to be `noexcept`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299324/why-is-stdmaps-move-constructor-not-noexcept). Some implementations may provide stronger guarantees than required by the standard, and make it `noexcept`; others may not.

The interaction of these two facts leads to a vector of maps of move-only type being non-portable - it may compile with some implementations but not others.